# Como adicionar um controller do MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit com C# no XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Eu to usando o MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit para criar o design do meu programa em WPF, sou novo em WPF e queria saber como eu posso adicionar o controller Card por C#, como eu faço com Button ou qualquer outro controller nativo do WPF

[MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)
[Cards.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Cards.xaml)
Card.cs ( Object source/API ) Não posso colocar mais de 2 links

Comment: Você quer adicionar um Card no *code behind* ou no *xaml*?

Comment: No xaml por c#  de um modo dinâmico, tipo eu vou receber dados do banco de dados e adicionar no card e depois colocar no xaml para o Usuário visualizar

Comment: Cards é um ContentControl. Você deve usá-lo como usa qualquer outro, podendo adicionar a ele qualquer control.

Comment: como eu faço para adicionar a imagem ? eu consigo fazer ele e adicionar o texto mas a imagem eu não sei como faz                                                                     var card = new Card();
card.Content = "texto";  help

Comment: Um ContentControl só pode ter um control. Se quer que o Card apresente mais de um deverá adicionar-lhe um Panel(Grid, StackPanel, etc) que contenha os controls que pretende, nesse caso um TextBlock e um Image

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!!  agora entendi como funciona, como eu posso positivar esse comentário? era exatamente o que estava procurando !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cards é um [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). Você deve usá-lo como usa qualquer outro, podendo adicionar a ele qualquer *control*.

No entanto, um ContentControl só pode ter um *control*.
Se quer que o Card apresente mais de um, deverá adicionar-lhe um *control* do tipo [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel(v=vs.110).aspx)(Grid, StackPanel, etc) que contenha os *controls* que pretende.